# How to return/improve accuracy when dividing joda time duration by an integer?

Tags: java, jodatime

I would like to calculate a a rate by returning the value to be multiplied by as a big decimal.
The relevant snippet of code below works:

```
Duration d1 = new Duration (startD, endD);
BigDecimal dur = new BigDecimal("0.00");
dur.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
dur = dur.add(new BigDecimal(d1.getStandardMinutes()/60));

return dur;
```

However, All I get is an integer without the scale.

Comment: Why are you rounding "0.00" to two decimal places and then discarding the result, and then adding the 0.00 to another number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
Duration d1 = new Duration (startD, endD);
BigDecimal dur = new BigDecimal(d1.getStandardMinutes()/60.0)
                      .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```